# Why use {% load static %} ? (in my case it didn't anything)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm New to coding and Python and also stack overflow
now I practice django and making blog tutorial and I have a question to you guys

How can I active {% load static %}? 
in my case without this, my css file works well..
and rather due to {% load static %}, in base.html
unexpected token is occurred 
which means that &lt!DOCTYPE html&gt is red underlined due to {% load static %}

Can you find any mistake in this code?
If I need to show you more codes, please let me know that
Thank you!

> setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '7sh#^-+*tczxfimk@+wq4s6jx$2(204&z9_d)mjomv1^y6644!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/base')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
#
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     "/Users/eunwoo/PycharmProjects/django_project/static"
#     , ]
```

> base.html
>
> > line 2  being red underlined when using {% load static %}
> >     and also when I uncomment {% load static %}, no error ocurred

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    <title>
        {% block title %}
        {% endblock title %}
    </title>

</head>
<body>
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">CHOs Blog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                    aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>


<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content-section">
                <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
                <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
WELCOME TO THIS BLOG
{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}

{% for item in post %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ item.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ item.date_posted |date:"M d, Y"}}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ item.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ item.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor post %}

{% endblock content %}
```

-------------Edit-----------------------------------------------

```
when uncomment `{% load static %}` unexpected token disappeared
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prQDY.png)

-------------Edit(2)-----------------------------------------------

[remove load static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjlGY.png) 
  [load static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQyyq.png)  
  [remove css ,line 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECMkS.png)

Comment: Is the problem that your CSS doesn't work when you use `{% load static %}`?

Comment: without {% load static %} CSS works, that's why I'm wondering 
I can't figure out why it works.
I want to make sure it

Comment: I also wonder how you can possibly have your template rendered if you remove the `{% load static %}` tag and keep using the `{% static %}` one - the template engine should raise an error here (all other considerations set aside) - which leads me to suspect you didn't really render the template after having removed the `{% load static %}`.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly this "unexpected token is occurred which means that &lt!DOCTYPE html&gt is red underlined due to {% load static %}" thing ? Where does this happen exactly ? (note that django templates are not HTML so if you use a strict HTML editor with validation, it will indeed crash on just any django template...).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't know why.. why I just uncommented `{% load static %}` is because of `&lt; !DOCTYPE  &gt;` underlined with red, after uncomment `{% load static %}` , `<!DOCTYPE >`shows no error. ( I'm going to edit my post for adding screenshot for this). anyway without `{% load static %}`  rendering Css is okay now.(though logically can't understand it)

Comment: Ok, what I suspected. __As I said__, this "unexpected token" is your code editor complaining that your template is not proper HTML. Which is indeed the case - it's a Django template, not a well-formed HTML doc -, so the solution to this is to configure your editor so it either knows about django templates syntax or at least doesn't bother you with false negative. But this won't explain how your template can possibly be rendered at all using templatetags that have not been properly imported.

Comment: I don't know how to do both of your ways. I'm very new to code.. Thanks for your advice. and lastly I add three pictures for more clear.

Answer (score -1):

@ **S.JIN**

You should use only templates on DIRS keys in the list of option. You wrote 'templates/base'.  So your template configuration in the list will be:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: actually , my base.html path is <br>
templates/base/base.html <br>
so when I change it to 'templates' , it makes TemplateDoesNotExist error

Comment: @S.JIN, Actually  your PyCharm editor need the django template tag environment. File » Settings » Template language  set django as template language setting. Please find out the option and set it so your editor can recognize the template tag for django.